# How to create structure at runtime and convert byte[] pointer to created structure?

Tags: c#

Usually we create structure at design time, create the object and assign the data at runtime. But I would like to create the structure at runtime.

I have the structure members and it's types as shown below.

```
Name, String
Age , Int32
Hobies[], sring[]
Height, float
temp[], byte[]
```

etc...

Now by using the above structure members, create the structure at runtime.
We  will have the byte array which will contain the data. I should Marshal it and convert it into created structure using PointerToStructure or something else.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to create a structure dynamically when you have all you need to create it in your code ? Creating it dynamically is meant to be used when you don't fully your structure at design time.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create a type at runtime, use [`System.Reflection.Emit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit) to create types at runtime.

But if the code that need to access the structure is native code, you can just write the byte array to the pointer with `Marshal.Copy` and it works fine with the native code that handles it as a structure, as long as the memory structure matches. The native code would never check if a provided pointer to a memory block is a defined structure or something else, just accesses the members with pointer offsets.

Please comment the actual need, and I will edit the answer to give more detailed help if you need.